# Use Electron with Database file

Tags: database, reactjs, electron

I have to build an application for a small company. I want to use a boilerplate which uses Electron, React Redux... but there is no server in the company. They want me to save a file on their network drive which can be accessed through the Electron  app.

In the past I used Microsoft Access to connect to an Access file on the drive. So far I found no package or something like that to connect to a database file.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/). Similarly to ms access it will store all your data in file + has all the power of SQL.

Here is a sample [boilerplate](https://github.com/sjmelia/electron-boilerplate-sqlite).